# How to generate apk for project using command prompt?

Tags: android, android-studio, build, apk

I need to build an apk using the **command prompt** for an Android Studio project.

My work space has two projects namely **Picasso** and **DemoProject**. The issue which  i am facing here is if I enter the command

`gradlew assembleDebug`

it is generating apks for two projects at same time but I need to generate only one apk for the **Picasso** project.

Suggest me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
gradlew :Picasso:assembleDebug
```

where "Picasso" in the cmd line should match the project name in your `settings.gradle`

Comment: Is there any other command to get the build from root directory?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the build"?

Answer (score -1):

**Create build.xml at project creation time**

If you start a new project with:

```
android create project \
--target 1 \
--name MyName \
--path . \
--activity MyActivity \
--package com.yourdomain.yourproject
```

the build.xml file used by ant will be generated.

**Create debug releases**

Besides:

```
ant release
```

for final releases, you can also create debug releases with:

```
ant debug
```

**Location of generated apk**

Generated apk are placed under bin/.

The most important outputs are:

```
MyName-debug.apk
MyName-release.apk
```

but some intermediate apks are also generated, in particular unaligned and unsigned versions.

But most of the time you can forget where they were created and just run:

```
ant debug install
ant release install
```

to get them installed. But make sure it is working with adb first:

Tested on Ubuntu 15.10, Android 23.

Comment: Seriosly, what is this? Has `ant`become a religion or something?

Comment: if do not want to use ant don't use it but why you down voted . i dont understant. i was trying to help you

Comment: 1. I downvoted not the OP. 2. I did it because you didnt answer the question the OP asked. He **clearly** mentioned that he is using gradle. U answered for a complete different build system!